# Im having trouble passing 2d arrays to my methods, then printing them, and also finding lowest value in certain data fields

Tags: arrays, methods, 2d

So I have all the information fine, but I have 3 problems, printing the methods, passing the array correctly, and in my getMinValue method im trying to get the lowest number out of the array [0][2] , [1][2],[2][2], [3][2],[4][2]. I'm pulling the wrong lowest numbers. Any help would be appreciated! (ignore my comments)

```
 public class MorenoJonathonSnowFallTotal
{
 public static void main(String[] args)
   {
   double [][] array={{3.6,24.6,31.8,26.4,17.5},
    {4.7,29.1,33.0,29.2,17.7},{5.5,23.3,41.0,26.7,14.4},
  {4.4,18.8,36.1,24.4,11.1},{2.1,10.1,18.8,18.8,8.9}};


/**for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
  for(int j=0;j<5;j++) {
    System.out.print(array[i][j]+" ");
}
System.out.println("");
} */
 //average by city


  //average by month

  System.out.println(monthAv);

 }
public static double getMinValue(double[][] numbers) {
    double minValue = numbers[0][2];
    for (int j = 1; j < 3; j++) {
        for (int i = 2; i < 3; i++) {
            if (numbers[j][i] < minValue ) {
                minValue = numbers[j][i];
            }
        }
    }
    return minValue ;
    }
 public void monthAv(double [][] arr)
 {
  double [][] array=arr;
  System.out.println("");
System.out.println("The average of November is "+(arr[0][0]+arr[1] . 
 [0]+arr[2][0]+arr[3][0]+arr[4][0])/5);
System.out.println("The average of December is "+(arr[0][1]+arr[1] . 
 [1]+arr[2][1]+arr[3][1]+arr[4][1])/5);
 System.out.println("The average of January is "+(arr[0][2]+arr[1] . 
 [2]+arr[2][2]+arr[3][2]+arr[4][2])/5);
 System.out.println("The average of Febuary is "+(arr[0][3]+arr[1] . 
[3]+arr[2][3]+arr[3][3]+arr[4][3])/5);
   System.out.println("The average of March is "+(arr[0][4]+arr[1] . 
  [4]+arr[2][4]+arr[3][4]+arr[4][4])/5);
   }
  public void cityAv(double[][] arr)
{
 double [][] array=arr;
   System.out.println("The average snow fall of Detroit is "+(array[0] . 
 [0]+array[0][1]+array[0][2]+array[0][3]+array[0][4])/5);
   System.out.println("The average snow fall of Chicago is "+(array[1] . 
 [0]+array[1][1]+array[1][2]+array[1][3]+array[1][4])/5);
 System.out.println("The average snow fall of Boston is "+(array[2] . 
  [0]+array[2][1]+array[2][2]+array[2][3]+array[2][4])/5);
 System.out.println("The average snow fall of New York is "+(array[3] . 
  [0]+array[3][1]+array[3][2]+array[3][3]+array[3][4])/5);
 System.out.println("The average snow fall of Washington D.C is "+ . 
 (array[4][0]+array[4][1]+array[4][2]+array[4][3]+array[4][4])/5);

  }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

There are too much syntax errors here and I'm not going to even mention them. I suggest you look for some java tutorials or books on the internet since there are a lot of them. Moreover the code is not complete. Also, the question is not very clear.

**Assuming that each row of your array are the values for a city and each column of those rows are the values of the city in the given month:**

**Read the comments** to get a general understanding of this problem *while following this code*:

```
    package morenojonathonsnowfalltotal;

public class MorenoJonathonSnowFallTotal {



    // Register cities
    public static final String[] CITIES = {
        "Detroid",
        "Chicago",
        "Boston",
        "New York",
        "Washington D.C."
    };
    // Register months
    public static final String[] MONTHS = {
        "November",
        "December",
        "January",
        "February",
        "March"
    };

    // ROW = City!
    // COL = Month!
    public static final double[][] DATA_2DARRAY = {
        //1º row will be temperatures of Detroid on November, December...
        //2º row will be temperatures of Chicago on November, December... AND SO ON AND SO FORTH
        {3.6, 24.6, 31.8, 26.4, 17.5},
        {4.7, 29.1, 33.0, 29.2, 17.7},
        {5.5, 23.3, 41.0, 26.7, 14.4},
        {4.4, 18.8, 36.1, 24.4, 11.1},
        {2.1, 10.1, 18.8, 18.8, 8.9}
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int column = 2;
        System.out.println("The lowest value for column "+column+" is: "+GetMinimumColumnValue(column));
        // You might mean or want...
        System.out.println("The lowest total snowfall on "+MONTHS[column]+" is: "+GetMinimumColumnValue(column));

        // Separate outputs.
        System.out.println("");System.out.println("");System.out.println("");
        ComputeMonthsAverageSnowfall();
        // Separate outputs
        System.out.println("");System.out.println("");System.out.println("");
        ComputeCitiesAverageSnowfall();
    }

    public static double GetMinimumColumnValue(int column) {
        /* 
           Init to the maximum double value so we ensure 
           that the value will be updated on the first iteration
        */
        double lowest = Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double current;
        // Traverse each month looking for the minimum value.
        for (int i = 0; i < MONTHS.length; i++) {
            current = DATA_2DARRAY[i][column];
            /* Update the minimal value if the current 
            element is lesser than the lowest we've found so far*/ 
            if(current<lowest) lowest=current;
        }
        return lowest;
    }

    public static void ComputeMonthsAverageSnowfall() {
        double average;
        for (int i = 0; i < MONTHS.length; i++) {
            // Compute it's average snowfall
            average = ComputeAverage(GetColumn(i));
            // Note that this time we have to get it's COLUMN values. hence GetColumn method.
            System.out.println("The average snowfall on "+MONTHS[i]+" was "+average);
        }
    }
    /**
     * Given an index of a column, copies all its values and returns it as an array.
     * @param idx_col
     * @return 
     */
    public static double[] GetColumn(int idx_col){
        // A Month register will hold as many registers as cities there are.
        // HENCE
        // The column will hold as many rows as the original data
        double[] col = new double[CITIES.length];
        // For each city, copy its values.
        for (int i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            col[i] = DATA_2DARRAY[i][idx_col];
        }
        return col;
    }
    public static void ComputeCitiesAverageSnowfall() {
        double average;
        // For each city...
        for (int i = 0; i < CITIES.length; i++) {
            // Compute it's average snowfall
            average = ComputeAverage(DATA_2DARRAY[i]);
            System.out.println("The average snowfall on "+CITIES[i]+" was "+average);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Computes the average value of this double array
     * @param array
     * @return 
     */
    public static double ComputeAverage(double[] array){
        double average = 0;
        // Sum each value from the array we want to compute average.
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            average = average + array[i];
        }
        // Return that sum divided by the total amount of elements that were in the array
        return (average/((double) array.length));
    }

}
```